# Force ebean to update the object

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a **Play Framework 2** application
I use play 2.2.2 built with Scala 2.10.3 (running Java 1.7.0_25).

I have a method that checks the object with his copy from secured table. If the object has been changed it will be replaced with the object from secured table.
But when I call save ebean does not update it:
*[debug] c.a.e.s.p.DefaultPersister - Update skipped as bean is unchanged*

```
public static <T> T findAndRestore(Class<T> clazz, Long id) throws Exception {
    T securedObject = SecuredEntityUtils.getObjectFromSecuredTable(clazz, id);
    T entity = Ebean.find(clazz, id);
    if (securedObject != null) {
        if (entity == null) {
            Ebean.save(securedObject);
        } else if (!entity.equals(securedObject)) {
            Ebean.update(securedObject);
        }
    } else {
        logger.warn("Not found securedObject for entity : " + entity.getClass());
    }
    return securedObject ;
}
```

Is there a way to force ebean to save/update entire object ?

Comment: I might be wrong but Ebean did not mark the entity as dirty since you did not called any setter on it.

Maybe using `Ebean.markAsDirty(entity)` could solve your issue (I know this is a pretty old question but since I stumbled upon it, maybe my answer could help somebody)

Comment: @RenaudHumbert-Labeaumaz You should post your answer rather than comment here. It solved my problem.

Comment: Done, I'm very glad it helped you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be wrong but Ebean did not mark the entity as dirty since you did not called any setter on it. Maybe using `Ebean.markAsDirty(entity)` could solve your issue (I know this is a pretty old question but since I stumbled upon it, maybe my answer could help somebody)

Comment: Looks like static use of Ebean is depreciated.